# Example for integrable function $f(x,y)$ such that $f_x$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Is there an example for integrable function $f(x,y)$ such that $f_x$ is not integrable.
Here $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$ Is a function of only one variable $y$, means that $x$ Is a constant.

I know that from Fubini's theorem, $f_x$ cannot be integrable only on a set of measure $0$.

So is such an example exists?

Comment: $f(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0,y)=D(y)$ -  Dirichlet-function

Comment: Are you sure $f(x,y)$ Is integrable?

Comment: It because the set of non continuity points are of measure $0$, right?

Comment: @Gabi: As an easier example, you can just take $f = 1_{\{0\} \times \Bbb{R}}$.

Comment: Thanks to you both!